# How to input user data through a text field, then display immediately below the text field?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript, but basically I want to take the users text, and once they hit the button, be able to output it below the button. This is what I have so far:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script>
    var message = "#";
    $("#message").text(message);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <var id="message"></var><textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Enter their post here, exactly word for word." id="post"></textarea></var>
        <button type="button">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What should happen if, after hitting 'the button' they type in another entry to the same input? Should that be appended, or should it replace the first entry?

Answer (score 0):

This is without jQuery.

Add an `id` to your button and create the empty text area with id `'textDiv'` and try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

         var button = document.getElementById('button_ID');
         button.addEventListener('click',showText);

         function showText() {
             document.getElementById('textDiv').innerHTML = 'new text'; 
         }    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button").click(function(){

   var text = document.getElementById("post").value;

   $("#message").html(text);
});



    <div id="wrapper">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Enter their post here, exactly word for word." id="post"></textarea>
    <button id="button" type="button">Submit</button>

    </div>

    <span id="message"></span>
```

Result:  http://jsfiddle.net/YoshiMaster/1r177khr/4/

Comment: Awesome, I found that this one worked and the second did not. Either way it's resolved.